# CardView suddenly turned black

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've got a problem with the `CardView` in the `RecyclerView`. 
My `CardView` suddenly became black and my `RatingBar` became blue. I'm using the `InfiniteRecyclerView` but changing it to the simple `RecyclerView` has no effect. I can change the `CardView`'s background colour to white but the `RatingBar` will still be blue. This is an example of what is happening:

[Black CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xzzl.png)

I use the normal `RecyclerView` in another activity within a fragment with the same adapter and it looks just fine. Here is an example:

[Normal CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf7Zw.png)

This is the `single_recipe_recycler_item.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <!-- RealmRecipe Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Very very very very very very long title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Publisher -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_publisher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/recipe_recycler_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Publisher"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/genre"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <!-- Rating -->
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_rating_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/recipe_recycler_publisher"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:max="5" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Why is this happening? Is there a bug in `CardView`? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What colour is `selectableItemBackground` in your `LinearLayout`?

Comment: That is background drawable for ripple effect. CardView became black before I applied `selectableItemBackground`, so it is not the reason of the problem.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing your app?

Comment: If it's 4.1.2, there is a problem with the `CardView` turning black in that version.

Comment: As this is most likely a Context issue, you should show some code, specifically your adapter. CardView theme (dark or light) depends on the context you use to inflate the views inside the adapter. This can be an Activity context (e.g. getActivity()) - in that case make sure your activity has a light theme. Or, for example, can be a View context (e.g. View.getContext()), and in that case android:theme matters etc.

Comment: I've just tried to use `getApplication()`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()` and so on instead of `this`, but that didn't help.
I also tried to change theme to SplashTheme, which has too more attributes 
`<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>` and `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>` for API 21+, and is used in MainActivity, where CardView is white, but that didn't help too. 
What part of adapter's code do you want to see?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and here is how I solved it. Make sure that your **Adapter** inflates the layout as follows. For you to understand better let's call this Adapter **MyAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_layout_person, null, true);

    }
```

Then for the **Activity** in which you'll be using your Adapter, make sure you're using the right Context. Now say we'll be using **MyAdapter** in an activity called **MyActivity**. The **wrong** ways to use the layout inflator with the **wrong** Context are as follows

1. First Wrong Way

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
                                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.recycler_row_layout_person, arrayList
                        );
   ```
2. Second Wrong Way

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
                                getContext(), R.layout.recycler_row_layout_person, arrayList
                        );
   ```

Here's the **RIGHT** way to do it. And this is the way I solved it.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
                                 MyActivity.this, R.layout.recycler_row_layout_person, arrayList
                         );
```

I HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: It looks as though this code is for an adapter for a `ListView`, not `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes, the problem was in using wrong context! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and tried this, it worked for me

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
```

Your XML file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">
```

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with the way the context was being referenced, but this worked.  I think maybe if you wrap the cardview in something else it may not be an issue either.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved by this style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
In my case I define the background in the wrong property, I used the default:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">
```

And you have to use the cardbackground property:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...      
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">
```

that did the trick for me. Cardview has is own properties and you have to use them instead of the default View properties. 
The same happens to the elevation property.