# Night Mode color is not applying to the recycler view background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-styles, android-night-mode, android-dark-theme

I want to implement night mode for my android app so I have used Theme.AppCompat.DayNight theme for implementing Night Mode.
But I have to customize the color of the Toolbar and recycler view during the Night Mode.

For that, I have declared the attribute in the attrs.xml file and use that attribute as a background in the recyclerview.

Here is the attrs.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ds">
        <attr name="rv_color" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here is the recyclerview

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/rv_color"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Now for styles, I have declared styles.xml and styles.xml (night) for Night Mode.

Here is the styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
    <item name="rv_color">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Here is the styles.xml (night)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
    <item name="rv_color">#FFFF00</item>
</style>
```

In the styles.xml file I have defined RED color for recyclerview background and YELLOW color in the night mode file.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

**The above line is present in the Activity file which to Night Mode.**

But Every time the recycler view color is RED i.e. from the styles.xml

Why styles.xml (night) color is not applying to the recyclerview.

Why it is not working? or any other way to do this?

Comment: Only `rv_color` is not working !?

Comment: Yes, other parameters values are set automatically from Night Mode like card background, text color, etc.

Comment: But I have to customize it.

Comment: @RohitSuthar hey, do you find any solution?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem (only that the RecyclerView always had the color defined in styles.xml (night), regardless of whether day or night mode was activated) and found a solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185880/cardview-suddenly-turned-black); the only thing I had to change was not to call

```
getApplicationContext()
```

but to use

```
MyActivity.this
```

instead when creating the Adapter with

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
```

in the corresponding Activity. Working solution:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, arrayList);
```

Comment: I've been having this problem for an hour, and this is the only solution that worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, I tried many days to find the solution to change theme, even I was not sure how to post this problem on StackOverflow to make people understand which error I'm getting,

Comment: Holy smokes you saved me so much painful years of debugging, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to create a values-night folder in your resources, place a colors.xml in it and declare a color like "rv_color":

```
<color name="rv_color">#ffff00</color>
```

and in the regular values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="rv_color">#ff0000</color>
```

Set the color of your recyclerview to that color. No need to declare any custom attribute.

Comment: I had defined color in both the files but it is not working.
Every time it is applying color from the colors.xml, not from colors.xml (night).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65066768/4676291
Please check out these comments.

Answer (score 0):

When I first tried implementing ondzilla's suggestion it didn't work. However, when I set the recyclerview background to another color I already had in the colors.xml file the background now toggles correctly between day/night. I then switched it back to rv_color and it works correctly.

No idea if this will help with yours but I'm super happy you asked this question and that mine now works.