# Night mode color values not applying to recycler view items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-night-mode

I implemented dark mode for my app. In the settings you can set it. Then it loads your option from sharedprefs and applies it using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode`. I made a function for this that I call at start of every activity.

```
fun setAppTheme(context: Context) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(when(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("theme", "default")) {
        "light" -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        "dark" -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        "default" -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
        else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
    })
}
```

It works great when i set it to follow system, all colors correct, but when I set it to force night mode, and change system mode to light, recycler view items are all light (should be dark!)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481456/night-mode-color-is-not-applying-to-the-recycler-view-background), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185880/cardview-suddenly-turned-black?noredirect=1&lq=1), tried using all the different contexts, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was I was calling the function `setAppTheme` right before `super.onCreate()` in main activity. My bad. This works now:

```
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setAppTheme(this)
...
```